# Change active tab

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have html code:

```
<ul class="tabs clearfix" style="margin:0px 5px;">
    <li class="" id="menu" class="active">
        <a href="#diagram" data-toggle="tab">Menu</a>
    </li>
    <li id="list">
        <a href="#month" data-toggle="tab">List</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

`li` elements are my tab that controlled by `bootstrap.min.js`.

Now I want change active tab with javascript:

```
function backBtn()
{
    var x = document.getElementById('list').className;
    if(x == 'active')
    {
        $("#list").removeClass('active');
        $("#menu").addClass('active');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Exit');
    }
}
```

Therefore I wrote this code to change it and it works
but when I change it I could not see active tab content.

Comment: nobody can help me???

Comment: [rtfm](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)